# why IPAddress() not working

Tags: c#, ip-address

I try to make a chat program between client and server and when I type this line :

IPAddress myIPAddress = new IPAddress( new byte[] (192,168,214,15));

it does not accepting it.. I run it on visual studio 2008 and it works well but in visual studio 2013 it doesn`t work and give me this error

Array Creation must have array size or array initializer

and after I add array size it pop ups with another bug :

```
// 1- Convert String to Bytes
        byte[] dataBuffer;
        dataBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox1.Text);

        // 2- Add TCP Client
        TcpClient myTcpClient = new TcpClient();

        // 3 - Connecting with Server
        IPAddress myIPAddress = new IPAddress( new byte[4] (192,168,214,15));
        myTcpClient.Connect(myIPAddress, 5020);

        // 4 - Add Network
        NetworkStream myNetworkStream = myTcpClient.GetStream();

        // 5 - Send message
        myNetworkStream.Write(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);

        // 6 - Close the Network Connection
        myNetworkStream.Close();
        myTcpClient.Close();
```

Is there any solution for it??

Method name expected

here is the full code :

Comment: For an array initializer, use `{192, 168, 214, 15}`. You could, however, use the static IPAddress.Parse method (or IPAddress.TryParse).

Comment: It is a simple typo, you have to use {curly braces}, not (parentheses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't initialize the array as you should.
Array initialization is done like this:

```
IPAddress myIPAddress = new IPAddress( new byte[] {192,168,214,15});
```

Anyway, you can iniitalize the IP address with `IPAddress.Parse`:

```
IPAddress myIPAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.214.15");
```

Either ways will work